# Edit html table using regular expressions php

Tags: php, html, regex

I am stuck and I was hoping that somebody could help me out.

I am creating a table from file data stored on a server.  I can get the table to populate like I want but I am having trouble trying to make a global change to the file.  Currently in the table it has peoples names but I would like to make it so that I can click on each individual name and have it linked to their email address.  Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Showing Groups</title></head>
<body>
<?php

  function DisplayRow($target) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    $parts = split(" +", $target);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i+=1) {
      print "<td>$parts[$i]</td>\n";
    }
    print "<td>\n";
    for ($i = 10; $i < count($parts); $i += 1) {
      print "$parts[$i] ";
    }
    print "</td>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";
  }

  print "<table border=1 width='95%'>\n";

  $allLines = file("cis.txt");
  foreach ($allLines as $oneLine) {     
    if (ereg("^[[:digit:]]", $oneLine)) {
      DisplayRow($oneLine);
    }  
  }
  print "</table>\n";


?>
</body>
</html>
```

This produces a table like this (but with table borders):

32133   CIS 100P    004 3.0 MW  1230    1359    CLOU    203 Wong, Jane S

I would make those names in column 10 to link to their email address like I said above.

I am trying to use this:

```
$oneLine=ereg_replace("^[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]+,[[:blank:]]
[[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]+$", 'x', $oneLine);
```

Where the regular expression recognizes that I am concerned with the names and the x is just being used because I was trying to see if it would work. I also need to know how I would change each individual name to use the first initial of the first name and up to 6 characters of the last name.

Thanks!

Comment: the email addresses will be the first initial of the first name (after the comma and the space) and then up to 6 characters of their last name.

Answer (score 0):

*Tip: make sure you post all info readers might need to know beforehand, like the format your email addresses are in. Now it was a bit unclear where you would get the addresses from until I read the comment to your post. Sometimes when working on a project you can forget that others have never seen it before and some things you might think are obvious and clear are unknown to the Stack Overflow readers.*

For what you want to do you could use regular expressions, but you don't actually have to. Depending on your skill (and how strict your source file has been formatted) you might prefer to use some simple substring methods instead.
By the way; capitalization doesn't matter in email addresses. If you still prefer a certain format for aesthetic reasons, you can use `strtoupper()`, `strtolower()`, `ucwords()` and `ucfirst()`. See the [PHP help](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) for more info on those methods.

A simple example:

```
<?php
    $name =  "Wong, Jane S"; // you get this from your .txt file
    $name_parts = explode(", ", $name); // Split the string by comma+space
    // Get the first character of the second part of the split string    
    echo substr($name_parts[1], 0, 1);
    // Get the first 6 characters of the last name, or if the name is less than
    // 6 characters long, it will get get the whole name
    echo substr($name_parts[0], 0, 6);
    echo "@example.com"
?>
```

If you really want a regular expression, you could try something like this:

```
// Get the first 1 to 6 characters in the a-z range that are before the comma
// Then get the first character after the comma and combine them
preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]{1,6}).+,\s([a-zA-Z])/', $name, $match);
echo $match[2].$match[1]."@example.com";
```

Take note that in both examples you might have to sanitize the email addresses to make sure they only contain valid characters (emails can't contain spaces for instance, but some names do use them (like `Van Helsing`)). How to sanitize those would depend on the formatting system you are using (clear the whitespace, replace with underscore / dash, etc.)